# Url filtering google custom search

Tags: search

How can I make google ONLY search a specific url WITHIN my site?

So it already will search everything and all the subpages, but I want it to ONLY search the home page or only search a specific sub page.

Only home page would be like: www.mysite.com
Specific subpage would be like www.mysite.com/somecategory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment due to my reputation, but I'm not sure what you are hoping to acheive. If the only result you want Google search to return is your home page, why not just send them to your home page. Similarly if the only result can be mysite.com/somecategory then why not just send the user to that page?

Are you actually looking for a way to bring up the Find bar to search the page they are already on?

Comment: It's an MVC app, that has urls like this: www.mysite.com/cat1, www.myite.com/cat2.  I want it to ignore the subsites and just return links from the top level url

Comment: I don't know that Google has that capability. But a workaround would be to create subdomains for each of your categories, then limit the search to those subdomains:
site:category1.mysite.com searchterm
And the subdomain category1 would be point to www.mysite.com/category1